# array to csv ignore comma in value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that converts an array to a csv file. It separates on commas but when there is a comma in one of the values of the array, it separates there as well. I've tried to wrap the comma in quotes and to escape it but it still breaks the csv. Any ideas on how to separate on comma but not from within the value of the array?

```
convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV: function(args) {
            var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

            data = args.data || null;
            if (data == null || !data.length) {
                return null;
            }

            columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
            lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

            keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

            result = '';
            result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
            result += lineDelimiter;

            data.forEach(function(item) {
                ctr = 0;
                keys.forEach(function(key) {
                    if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

                    result += item[key];
                    ctr++;
                });
                result += lineDelimiter;
            });

            return result;
        },
        downloadCSV: function(args) {
            var data, filename, link, csvArray;

            csvArray = ids.map(function(id) {
                return {
                    'id': id.id,
                    'image': id.image,
                    'desc': id.desc
                };
            });
            var csv = utilities.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
                data: csvArray
            });


            if (csv == null) return;

            filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

            if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
                csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
            }
            data = encodeURI(csv);

            link = document.createElement('a');
            link.setAttribute('href', data);
            link.setAttribute('download', filename);
            link.click();
        }
    };
```

Here is a sample of the data created as csvArray:

```
[{id:123,
image:image,
desc : "hello here is a comma , I am after the comma"}]
```

Comment: quote your text values with double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change how you write text to result as below

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    ctr = 0;
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;
        result += "\"" + item[key].replace(/"/g, '\\"') + "\"";
        ctr++;
    });
    result += lineDelimiter;
});
```

Just adding text in between quotes may solve this issue.

Comment: Should escape internal double quotes also ... in case they exist